# How to create separate admin panel for customer in joomla 3?

Tags: joomla3.0

I am working on a project where my client has no idea about joomla admin panel.
So I have decided to provide a separate admin pannel which my client can access and manage few things.
I am also having multiple pages and sub-pages in this admin panel.
Lets say I want to give multiple manage links.

- manage item

  - sub-menu
- manage item 2

I am little confuse how do I do it, once I thought about component and moduel but I don't know how to add menu links in components for front end. 
I am using joomla 3.0.

Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your intention is creating a backend alternative to joomla to control joomla's frontend, this is a hard thing to do if you are just a e-commerce website developer.

But if you need a different account other than your administrator account, you can add one account and edit it's privileges.

Comment: Thanks for quick response, and i will do same.

Answer (score 0):

A second admin panel for easier use? sorry that sounds not good. Just do it like serhat above said. make a new account for joomla admin-panel. cut of the privileges so the user see only the things he has access to! its better then coding a fully new admin panel. there is already a fully configurable panel so why do another one?

Give the users just what they have to see and hide the rest (via admin-privileges)